# Generating a random MAC address

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need the ability to generate random MAC addresses, so I wrote up a little function that does that:

```
>>> random_mac()
'7C:93:B7:AF:BA:AE'
>>> random_mac()
'D8:D8:A0:D4:A5:3F'
>>> random_mac(unicast=False, universal=True)
'55:47:C6:EE:C6:2B'
>>> random_mac(unicast=True, universal=False)
'FE:A1:4B:98:76:B6'
```

I decided to allow the user to pick if it's unicast/multicast and universally/locally administered; even though I'll only need unicast/universal. This caused me headaches though because I'm still not great at dealing with bits. [The LSB of the first octet indicates uni/multicast, and the second LSB of the octet indicates universal/local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#/media/File:MAC-48_Address.svg), so these bits can't be random.

After playing around with a few failed ideas (generating all random bits, then "fixing" the two bits later), I finally decided to generate a random number between 0 and 63 inclusive, left shift it twice, than add the two bits on after. It works, but it's ugly and looks suboptimal.

It's not a lot of code, but I'd like a few things reviewed:

- Is there a better approach? It feels hacky generating it as two pieces then adding them together. I tried [explicitly setting the bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/3000206), but the code to decide between `|`, and `&` and `~` got messier than what I have now, so I went with this way.
- The number constants are bugging me too. The numbers kind of sit on a border of self-explanatory and magic, so I decided to name them to be safe. `LAST_SIX_BITS_VALUE` feels off though.
- Is treating a boolean value as a number during bitwise operation idiomatic? Is it clear as I have it now?
- Attaching the first octet to the rest is suboptimal as well. Speed isn't a huge concern, but I'm curious if there's a cleaner way that I'm missing.

---

```
from random import randint, randrange

N_MAC_OCTETS = 6
OCTET_VALUE = 256
LAST_SIX_BITS_VALUE = 63

def random_mac(unicast: bool = True, universal: bool = True) -> str:
    least_two_bits = (not unicast) + ((not universal) << 1)
    first_octet = least_two_bits + (randint(0, LAST_SIX_BITS_VALUE) << 2)
    octets = [first_octet] + [randrange(OCTET_VALUE) for _ in range(N_MAC_OCTETS - 1)]
    return ":".join(f"{octet:02X}" for octet in octets)
```

---

Examples of the bits for the first octet for different inputs:

```
def display(mac):
    print(mac, f"{int(mac.split(':')[0], 16):08b}")

# Unicast, Universal
>>> display(random_mac(True, True))
04:27:DE:9A:1B:D7 00000100  # Ends with 0,0

# Unicast, Local
>>> display(random_mac(True, False))
72:FB:49:43:D5:F2 01110010  # 1,0

# Multicast, Universal
>>> display(random_mac(False, True))
7D:BF:03:4E:E5:2A 01111101  # 0,1

# Multicast, Local
>>> display(random_mac(False, False))
2F:73:52:12:8C:50 00101111  # 1,1
```

Comment: small suggestion, it might help to look at how the library `randmac` does it. [randmac Python 3](https://pypi.org/project/randmac/)

Comment: would it help that you deal with nibbles instead of octet?

Comment: @AryanParekh That's a good idea. For some reason I never even considered that there would be a library for this. I'll check it out.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I don't really care too much about the implementation (except for readability) providing the end result is the same. It may ease it a bit though to deal with the "special nibble" on its own, then add it in to the rest of the octet. That would make some of the magic constants simpler numbers.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that's cool, I assume that you might have wanted to create your own method rather than using a library, if that's not the case, prefer using the library as the class from the library is really useful, with methods that allow you to use different formats,

Comment: Note that some locally-administered addresses are well-known addresses. You should not gazump those. Basically, avoid 0?:??:??:??:??:?? to 6?:??:??:??:??:?? inclusive for LAs.

Comment: @vk5tu Stuff like that is why for my actual project, I ended up abandoning the two parameters. I'm glad I posted this question because I learned a lot, but only global/unicast make sense for my application, and multicast/local have their own nuances that make them inappropriate to randomize; at least not without a lot more considerations that I'm not wiling to deal with.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Negating an argument is somewhat counterintuitive. Consider passing them as `multicast` and `local` instead.
- I would seriously consider defining

  ```
    UNIVERSAL = 0x01
    MULTICAST = 0x02
  ```

  and pass them as a single argument, is in

  ```
        random_mac(UNIVERSAL | MULTICAST)
  ```
- Using both `randint` and `randrange` feels odd. I would stick with `randrange`.
- First octet needs a special treatment anyway. That said, consider

  ```
    def random_mac(special_bits = 0):
        octets = [randrange(OCTET_VALUE) for _ in range(N_MAC_OCTETS)]
        octets[0] = fix_octet(octet[0], special_bits)
        return ":".join(f"{octet:02X}" for octet in octets)
  ```

  with

  ```
    def fix_octet(octet, special_bits):
        return (octet & ~0x03) | special_bits
  ```

Comment: @Carcigenicate: `fix_octet` just clears the low 2 bits, then ORs in what should be there.  Looks very comprehensible to me, and exactly what I would have suggested if there wasn't already an answer doing that. (Generating all 6 octets the same way and modifying 1 is also what I was going to suggest). Getting the caller to pass ORed bitflags is great; it simplifies the implementation and makes the call-site more self-documenting. (And is a common idiom in C for system calls like `mmap(..., MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | ...)`, or for ORing together permission bit flags, or lots of other things.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I may be misunderstanding something, but I was just saying that this currently seems to give an incorrect result. I think it's because the flags need to be `MULTICAST = 0x01; LOCAL = 0x02` instead of what they currently are.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I was replying to your first comment.  You second comment didn't point out what the problem was or give an example, and I didn't notice the bit-flags definitions were backwards.  But yes, `0x1` is the LSB, `0x2` is the second bit, so that matches your question (and wikipedia).

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, now this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: After changing the flags to `MULTICAST = 0x01; LOCAL = 0x02`, this does indeed give the correct output. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 11):

## Some observations on the API

### Naming

The IEEE *strongly discourages* use of the name *MAC* or *MAC-48*. These names should only be used as an obsolete label for *EUI-48*.

It is also imprecise, since not all MAC addresses are EUI-48 addresses. For example, FireWire MAC addresses are EUI-64.

So, your function should probably be named `random_eui48` instead.

### Keyword-only arguments

Having two boolean parameters can lead to confusion. I would make them [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) so that the caller is always forced to name them:

```python
def random_eui48(*, unicast: bool = True, universal: bool = True) -> str:
```

### Defaults

I agree with the choice of making Unicast the default. It is probably what users will usually need more often. However, I *disagree* with making universally administered addresses the default. In fact, I find it highly dubious to randomly generate UAAs *at all*. At most, you should randomly generate addresses *within an OUI you own*.

So, I would very much prefer to make LAAs the default.

### Choice of parameters

I would choose the parameters such that they are "off-by-default" (`False`) and ca be "turned on" by the caller:

```python
def random_eui48(*, multicast: bool = False, universal: bool = False) -> str:
```

### API extension: supply OUI

It really only makes sense to generate a UAA *within an OUI you own*. Therefore, your API should provide for passing in a OUI to generate an addresses for. Make sure you take care of both the MAC-S and MAC-L registries!

## Implementation

An EUI-48 is a 48 bit number. I find it strange to treat it as a conglomerate of 5 8 bit and one 6 bit number.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding "EUI-48", is "MAC" simply not used in industry, or should it only be avoided when you're referring to a physical address of a certain length? I've actually never heard of "EUI-48" before; beyond the mention on the Wiki page. And as for why I'm randomizing the OUI as well: I'm writing a malicious DHCP client and need random MACs so that I can continue requesting new addresses while keeping the previous addresses on lease.

Comment: Oh, MAC is being used all over the place, it's just that the IEEE strongly advises against it. If you *really are* talking about MAC addresses, I think it makes sense to use the term "MAC", but be aware that, depending on the protocol, MAC addresses need not be 48 bit. And conversely, EUIs are used for addresses other than MAC addresses. E.g. the Clock ID in the Precision Type Protocol is an EUI, albeit an EUI-64.

Comment: I'm not sure the IEEE disapproves of the use of "MAC" as a general term. Rather, my understanding is that the term "MAC-48" is deprecated in favour of "EUI-48". "MAC address" usually refers to how the identifier is used, where as "[MAC/EUI]-48" refers to the numbering scheme.

Answer (score 2):

`random.randrange()` takes *start*, *stop*, and *step* arguments just like `range()`.  To select the first octet, *start* is based on the unicast and universal flags, *end* is 256, and *step* is 4 (four possible combinations of unicast and universal).

```
N_MAC_OCTETS = 6
OCTET_VALUE = 256
LAST_SIX_BITS_VALUE = 63

def random_mac(unicast: bool = True, universal: bool = True) -> str:
    first_octet = randrange(3 ^ (universal*2 + unicast), OCTET_VALUE, 4)
    octets = [first_octet] + [randrange(OCTET_VALUE) for _ in range(N_MAC_OCTETS - 1)]
    return ":".join(f"{octet:02X}" for octet in octets)
```

or better:

```
UNICAST = 0
MULTICASE = 1

UNIVERSAL = 0
LOCAL = 2

def random_mac(flags: int = UNICAST | UNIVERSAL) -> str:
    first_octet = randrange(flags, OCTET_VALUE, 4)
    octets = [first_octet] + [randrange(OCTET_VALUE) for _ in range(N_MAC_OCTETS - 1)]
    return ":".join(f"{octet:02X}" for octet in octets)
```

Called like:

```
random_mac(LOCAL | MULTICAST)
```

Comment: Using `universal = True` for unicast is the opposite of the bit value. That is, when `unicast` it true the bit value is false.  Similarly for `universal`.  This smells like a source of bugs.  I'd suggest changing the parameters to `multicast` and `local` so they match the bit values or, as vnp suggested, define some constants that can be or-ed.

Answer (score 2):

While still using @vnp's `fix_octet()` function, an alternate approach might be

```py
def random_mac(special_bits = 0):
    return ':'.join('%02x'%randint(0,255) if i != 0 else '%02x'%fix_octet(randint(0,255),special_bits) for i in range(6))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(not unicast) + ((not universal) << 1)
```

- When manipulating bits or bitfields, use `|`, not `+`. Even though the result will be the same here, the semantic is different.
- You read left-to-right. So handle the bits left to right.
- I do agree with the fact that negations quickly mess with your head.

I'd rather write:

```
(local << 1) | multicast
```

Going one step further, I'd replace:

```
least_two_bits = (not unicast) + ((not universal) << 1)
first_octet = least_two_bits + (randint(0, LAST_SIX_BITS_VALUE) << 2)
```

With

```
first_octet = (randint(0, LAST_SIX_BITS_VALUE) << 2) | (local << 1) | multicast
```

You could define `LAST_SIX_BITS_VALUE` as `((1 << 6)-1)` to make it more explicit that its value comes from the need for 6 bits. One step further would be to define

```
FIRST_OCTET_RANDOM_BITS_NUMBER = 6
FIRST_OCTET_RANDOM_BITS_MAX_VALUE = (1 << FIRST_OCTET_RANDOM_BITS_NUMBER) - 1
```

I agree that mixing `randint` (where the top value is inclusive) and `randrange` (where it isn't) is confusing.